# Excel - find duplicate values with shared data and determine which one was "created" first

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a table with 3 different categories of data: Time, Value, ID. There will be multiple Value's that correspond to each ID, but then those Values might also be duplicated later on.  Essentially each ID is a "folder" and the Value's are files.  I need to find all the instances in which a "file" occurs in another "folder".  On top of that, I need to determine which files were added to their respective folder first.  Here's an example:

TIME . . . . Value . . . . ID

1:00 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . A

2:00 . . . . . 2 . . . . . . . . A

3:00 . . . . . 3 . . . . . . . . A

4:00 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . B

5:00 . . . . . 4 . . . . . . . . B

6:00 . . . . . 2 . . . . . . . . C

I would need the program to output a table similar to this:

Original ID . . . New ID

A . . . . . . . . . . . B

A . . . . . . . . . . . C

The program, in this situation, is locating the recurrences of the "Value"s, and then determining which ID corresponds to the earliest time.  I've been going at it with For loops and uncomfortable amounts of If/Then statements, but it just gets more and more cluttered.  Hopefully one of you all can help! Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You will be more likely to get responses if you can share the code you've written thus far.  See how to ask a good question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you can use formula to get what you want.  Does it have to be vba?

Comment: @ScottCraner no it doesn't necessarily have to be VBA but I didn't think there was a formula that could do that.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Demetri I'll post some of the for loops and if/then statements I've started with but none of it is really complete code.  It's just things I've started with, and then realized that it won't work once I've gotten a step or two into it.  So basically any input is helpful.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: @ScottCraner woops I somehow managed to completely miss it.  I'll test it out and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it in vba:

```
Sub RobH()

Dim OID As String
Dim NID As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    For Each rng In .Range("A2:A7")
        OID = .Evaluate("=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7," & rng.Offset(, 1).Value2 & ")>1,INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(MIN(IF($B$2:$B$7=" & rng.Offset(, 1).Value2 & ",$A$2:$A$7)),$A$2:$A$7,0)),""Unique"")")
        NID = .Evaluate("=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7," & rng.Offset(, 1).Value2 & ")>1,INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(MAX(IF($B$2:$B$7=" & rng.Offset(, 1).Value2 & ",$A$2:$A$7)),$A$2:$A$7,0)),""Unique"")")
        If OID <> NID And OID <> rng.Offset(, 2) Then
            Debug.Print OID & " " & NID
        End If
    Next rng
End With
End Sub
```

It uses the basic formula of:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,E2)>1,INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(MIN(IF($B$2:$B$7=E2,$A$2:$A$7)),$A$2:$A$7,0)),"unique")
```

This gets the first occurance.  To get the last change the MIN to a MAX:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,E2)>1,INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(MAX(IF($B$2:$B$7=E2,$A$2:$A$7)),$A$2:$A$7,0)),"unique")
```

In both E2 is the cell which holds the value to be tested.  Both are array formulas and need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.